How to manage a shared private package between two apps using Git?
I need to create a design system that will be shared between two separate apps. One option I'm considering is creating a private Git repository to host the design system, and then using versioning via branches to manage updates. Could anyone provide guidance on the full process for managing a shared design system in this way?
Specifically, I need advice on:

How to structure the repository to support versioning for two apps.

Best practices for managing updates and ensuring both apps are in
sync with the latest changes.

Recommendations for handling breaking
changes and version increments.

How to handle backward compatibility between versions for the
apps.


